# MySQL + PHP In MySQL IF statement is wrong? How to create simple If statement MySQL 5.50?

Tags: mysql

I use this code but I see syntax error.

**MYSQL 5.5.50.0**

```
IF 2>1 THEN

SELECT "HELLO WORLD!"

END IF;
```

EDIT: This code Will not work. Because IF Statement only using FUNCTION and procedure.

Error is:

```
SQL-ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF 2>1 THEN
```

my readSql($sql) function is working most case. I think my MySQL code is wrong.

What is wrong?
Thank you.

EDIT:

IF Statement only using FUNCTION and procedure.

Comment: [`IF` in that form](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) only works inside a stored procedure, not as an arbitrary statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL IF() takes three expressions and if the first expression is true, not zero and not NULL, it returns the second expression. Otherwise, it returns the third expression.

Depending on the context in which it is used, it returns either numeric or string value.

```
 IF(expression ,expr_true, expr_false);
```

For example, you could have a query:

```
SELECT IF(1>3,'true','false'); 
#return false
```

If you just want return the string 'HELLO WORLD' , you could use:

```
 SELECT  CASE WHEN 2 > 1 THEN 'HELLO WORLD'  END
```